# How to rebuild a existing Dom in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom, reactjs

I am currently trying to get reactJS working with the following Setup:

I am getting a xml-DOM from the Server. Its a server side rendered "custom" DOM, which normaly gets consumed by another client (not html, but java) which renders components.

```
<row id="a">
    <label id="aa" width="140" text="Title" />
    <field id="ab" bgpaint="" width="200" text="" enabled="true" />
</row>
```

I defined some ReactComponents with React.createClass(). So I have a Label, a Field and a Row (div).

Currently I cannot work out a way to render the Components of the xml-DOM with react.
I am going trough the xml-DOM and got the snippet from above. If I find a "row" shell I call React.createElement(Row, {}, ?)? But I i dont know what children will be to fill the '?' before I go deeper into the xml-DOM.
If I walk through the xml-DOM until I got a "endNode" with no children, how can i create the react elements from bottom to top? Do I have to create a super String and somehow call it as javascript.

Is there a way to create a Row, and afterwads add the children? Do I have to use the components props?
Something like:

```
//<row> found
var newRow = React.createElement(Row, {}, ?);
...
//found the label in the row
var newLabel = React.createElement(Label, {}, "Title");
newRow.add(newLabel);
```

I can hardly come to a solution - is it possible to do with react? Or am I trying to do something which react is not made for? Probably I do not understand the child concept totally.
Or maybe its not really a react-Problem itself...

Any hints for me?

greetz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the children array before you call createElement. For example ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rtnw2wvf/2/)):

```
function pascalize(str) {
    return str.split("-").map(function(name) {
        return name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1).toLowerCase();
    }).join("");
}

function attrsToProps(attrs) {
    var obj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < attrs.length; ++i) {
        obj[attrs[i].nodeName] = attrs[i].value;
    }
    return obj;
}

function toReact(node, components) {
    if (node.nodeType === 1) {
        var children = [].map.call(node.childNodes, function(child) {
            return toReact(child, components);
        });
        return React.createElement(components[pascalize(node.nodeName)],
                                    attrsToProps(node.attributes),
                                    children);
    } else if (node.nodeType === 3) {
        return (node.nodeValue + "").trim();
    }
    return "";
}

function xmlToReactComponents(xmlDom, components) {
    if (xmlDom && xmlDom.documentElement) {
        return React.createElement("div", [], [].map.call(xmlDom.documentElement.childNodes, function(child) {
            return toReact(child, components);
        }));
    }
}
```

The usage in jsfiddle is:

```
var xml = document.querySelector("#xml").innerHTML;
var parser = new DOMParser();
var dom = parser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");

var defaultClass = {
    render: function() {
        return React.createElement("div", {}, "id: " + this.props.id, this.props.children);
    }  
};

var components = {
    Row: React.createClass(defaultClass),
    Label: React.createClass(defaultClass),
    Field: React.createClass(defaultClass)
}
var result = xmlToReactComponents(dom, components);
React.render(result, document.body);
```

You need to pass all the components the xml could create in the object otherwise whole thing fails

Comment: You could just represent it as `Tree {component: String, props: Object, children: [Tree]}` and just `.children.map(renderTree)` to recursivley render.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand and how do you get reference to the component class?

Comment: The components object in your example is a mapping of component names to component classes.  That's exactly what I'd use.

Comment: The approach @FakeRainBrigand ist mentioning was also my first idea. The Tree itself is easly build by parsing the sent xml, but the _"...  and just .children.map(renderTree)"_-Part is the crucial point, which I lack of a "code"-way.

Comment: I somehow didn't realize I didn't have to use `with` lol, now it's much cleaner. There is no need to build any representation.

Comment: Hi! Awesome. I played a little bit with the fiddle example and I'm thinking I did get the idea. Thx a lot!